# Adding Multi-choice Questions faster in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I need to create a **Google form** using **Google Docs**, for surveying purposes. Several of the questions I am incorporating in the form consist of multiple choices, which my colleague has listed down in an Excel spreadsheet.

As of now, the only way I know to put these choices into each question is cutting & pasting each one of them into the appropriate text box.

Is there a faster / more efficient way of doing this (maybe, using some script)?

(For example, something like copying from a spreadsheet column directly into the Google form creation interface)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to link a "Choose from a list" style question in a Google Form to a list of data (e.g. in a spreadsheet)?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40292/is-there-a-way-to-link-a-choose-from-a-list-style-question-in-a-google-form-to)

Answer (score 1):

In your spreadsheet copy the column of cells with your choices. (Don't copy the whole column.)

In the form's multiple choice question select "Option 1".

Paste in your cells. (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> on Mac)