# Is there a script to draw a list of variables from a table to Google Forms?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-apps-script, google-forms

I would like to have a field in Google Forms that allows the user to select a value from a "List" of values. The options in the list being drawn from a list in the sheet itself.

This allows me to add a value to the sheet, which then adds it to the list of items to choose from.

Is there a script available for this? 
Or do I have to manually add 500 items to my list for the user to choose from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was brought up a few times on the site having posts with very different, concrete, working approaches.

- for a simple copy-paste (non-dynamic solution) please have a look at: [Adding Multi-choice Questions faster in Google Forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/7953/117311)
- by using a script please read : [Is there a way to link a "Choose from a list" style question in a Google Form to a list of data (e.g. in a spreadsheet)?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40292/117311)
- and [How to create a countries drop-down list question, without entering all countries manually?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/76189/117311)
- as well as: [How do I create a multiple choice question in Google Forms based on spreadsheet data?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/53383/117311)

Within the above answers there is mention of the free add-ons [Form Values](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-values/cggfolheomgjfjibllgbakdnjdiiienb) and [formRanger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/formranger/faepkjkcpnnghgdhiobglpppbfdnaehc) which both automate the procedure without the need for you to write any code.